# Quill with Vue v-model without npm

Tags: vue.js, quill, v-model

I'm using vuejs with quill.

I'm not using npm or any other build tools, only linking vuejs and quill.min.js in the header of my html.

If quill works, v-model doesn't and vice versa.

```
    <div id="editor">
       <input class="textarea" v-model="email_content">
    </div>
```

and

```
  <input id="editor" class="textarea" v-model="email_content">
```

or

```
<div id="editor">
    <textarea class="textarea" v-model="email_content"></textarea>
</div>
```

doesn't do the job.
Console doesn't show any error.

Comment: The html is over 400 lines ... so should <input id="editor" class="textarea" v-model="email_content"> work?

Comment: I found out that quill-editor can fire a 'text-change' event, so I'll will go for a workaround. Thanks